# Arel, nested NamedFunction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arel

I'm trying to compose this query via Arel:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(4)) * 1000) FROM Table1
```

Using http://www.scuttle.io/ it return a simply:

```
Table1.select(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'ROUND', [
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
        'UNIX_TIMESTAMP', [Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CURTIME', [4])]
      ) * 1000
    ]
  )
)
```

but my rails app doesn't accept it, giving me:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `*' for #<Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction:0x0000000c7471e0>):
```

There's a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used this part of Arel, and I can't test this right now, but I'm guessing that instead of `*` you need to use [Arel::Nodes::Multiplication](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/Nodes/Multiplication):

```
Arel::Nodes::Multiplication.new(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'UNIX_TIMESTAMP', [Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CURTIME', [4])]
  ),
  1000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Table1.select(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
    'ROUND', [
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
        'UNIX_TIMESTAMP', [Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CURTIME', [4])]
      ) * 1000
    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: Am I going crazy or is this identical to OP's code?

Comment: Sorry, I must have pasted the OP's post instead my own answer >,<